# Red Hat Enterprise Linux の開発者用サブスクリプションについて

Tags: linux, rhel

あまりプログラミング等とは少し逸れた質問を投稿させて頂き誠に申し訳ありません。

表題に記載させて頂いております通り、私は開発者用サブスクリプションを利用して、RHEL 8.2を去年の8月2日から1年間、検証用OSとして無償利用させて頂いてきておりました。

検証用マシンとはいえ、OS設定や導入したミドルウェアなど、本番機さながらに作りこんだ仮想マシンなのですが、期限が迫ってきているため、ひとまずサブスクリプションの更新をHP上で行ったのですが（多分できているはず…）、このような処置を取ることで若干でも期間延長して使用することができるようになるのでしょうか。

また、仮にサブスクリプション更新を行わなかった場合、どうなりますか？
特に今から新たにパッケージをインストールしたりアップデートをかけることもないので、
その辺りだけ制限がかかるということでしたら特に支障ないのですが、Windows Serverのように数十分？したら落ちるとかになるとキツイです。

インフラ～DBエンジニアをやっているため少しサイトの趣旨に合った質問ではないかもしれませんが、同じような境遇になられて、更新または更新しなかったなどのご経験があられる方はどのようになるのかご教授頂けますと幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「開発者用」のサブスクリプション自体は利用したことが無いので一般的な話になりますが、サブスクリプションが有効期限切れ (割り当てが無い) 状態になることで機能的な制限がかかるのはパッケージのアップデート等が入手できなくなる等のみで、OS の起動には影響ありません。

[サブスクリプションを更新しない場合の手続き](https://www.redhat.com/ja/explore/information/unsubscription)

サブスクリプションの更新を (webサイト上で) 行った場合にも、システム (サーバ) へ割り当てられた証明書が更新されているかを念のため確認した方が良さそうです。

[サブスクリプション証明書の更新](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/certs-update)